# MySQL self join to get ordered parent-child records

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data, self-join

I have a table with the following structure:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| member_id | household_id | firstName | lastName |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14122     | 0            | Cynthia   | Bookout  |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14123     | 0            | Kim       | Caves    |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14124     | 14122        | Marvin    | Bookout  |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14125     | 13974        | Stacey    | Webb     |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14126     | 13974        | Nathan    | Webb     |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14127     | 13974        | Adam      | Webb     |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14128     | 13974        | Thomas    | Webb     |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14129     | 0            | Missy     | Hammock  |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14130     | 0            | Stephanie | Lewis    |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14131     | 0            | Kelly     | Hutto    |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14132     | 14130        | James     | Lewis    |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14133     | 0            | Cindy     | Barnwell |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14134     | 13828        | NATALIE   | MCMILLAN |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14135     | 13828        | Steven    | Adams    |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| 14136     | 0            | Katherine | Gaskins  |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

`member_id` and `household_id` have a parent-child relationship for certain records. For example, record with `member_id` 14124 is the child of `member_id` 14122 (i.e., its `household_id` is the `member_id` of its parent).

The table actually contains thousands of records that are not in order. I want to display them such that the parent is followed by its child records, and then the next parent and its child records appear, and so on. The result needs to be sorted by `member_id`, too.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE household_id IN (SELECT member_id FROM members WHERE household_id = 0) OR household_id = 0
ORDER BY member_id
```

But I do not get the desired results. Doing it programatically using PHP is taking too long since I have to iterate each record many times.

This is my desired result:

```
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| member_id | household_id | firstName    | lastName |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14122     | 0            | Cynthia      | Bookout  |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14124     | 14122        | Marvin Keith | Bookout  |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14123     | 0            | Kim          | Caves    |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14125     | 13974        | Stacey       | Webb     |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14126     | 13974        | Nathan       | Webb     |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14127     | 13974        | Adam         | Webb     |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14128     | 13974        | Thomas       | Webb     |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14129     | 0            | Missy        | Hammock  |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14130     | 0            | Stephanie    | Lewis    |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14132     | 14130        | James        | Lewis    |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14131     | 0            | Kelly        | Hutto    |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14133     | 0            | Cindy        | Barnwell |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14134     | 13828        | NATALIE      | MCMILLAN |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14135     | 13828        | Steven       | Adams    |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 14136     | 0            | Katherine    | Gaskins  |
+-----------+--------------+--------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT a.member_id as parent_id,
       a.firstName as parent_firstName,
       a.lastName as parent_lastName,
       b.member_id as child_id,
       b.firstName as child_firstName,
       b.lastName as child_lastName
FROM members a inner join members b on a.member_id = b.household_id
ORDER BY a.member_id
```

[query_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mzNp.jpg)

Comment: This is not what I was looking for! I want Parent record followed by child record, EACH IN A DIFFERENT ROW.